# Changing media query

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to set a media query for this script with no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Basically, I would like the `.style.width = 50%` to be `100%` on small screen sizes. :/

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue, not a javascript one.  I'd consider creating a class, with a media query override, then you can add/remove that class

Comment: you need to provide more detail about the issue, also you need to provide your HTML so people may know if your HTML is actually talking to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openNav() {
  if (window.innerWidth < your_width)
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
  else
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

For example... But I would use CSS